# How will changing the mysql field type from INT to VARCHAR affect data previously stored as an INT

Tags: mysql, varchar

I need to update a field in my production db from INT to VARCHAR.

The information in the current INT field is sensitive and I want to ensure that I don't alter it inadvertently or destroy it while changing the table type. For example, a user may have INT 123456 stored in this column and I want to ensure that is accurately stored once converted to VARCHAR.

What is the recommended process for accomplishing this?

Is there anything I need to worry about when using something like this?

```
ALTER TABLE table_sample CHANGE col_sample col_sample VARCHAR;
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Get your MySQL server into strict mode before you change the column type and make sure that your `varchar(n)` column has a large enough `n` to hold all of the integers when they're converted to strings. If you're not in strict mode then MySQL will [silently truncate your data to fit your string size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/char.html):

> If strict SQL mode is not enabled and you assign a value to a `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` column that exceeds the column's maximum length, the value is truncated to fit and a warning is generated. For truncation of nonspace characters, you can cause an error to occur (rather than a warning) and suppress insertion of the value by using strict SQL mode.

But if you get into [strict mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#:%7E:text=ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO%20%2C%20and%20NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION%20.-,Strict%20SQL%20Mode,be%20invalid%20for%20several%20reasons.&text=For%20statements%20such%20as%20SELECT,strict%20mode%2C%20not%20an%20error.) first:

```
mysql> set sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';
mysql> alter table table_sample change col_sample col_sample varchar(6);
```

You'll get a nice error message like this:

```
ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'col_sample' at row ...
```

if your integers don't all fit in your `varchar`.

And, of course, you will have a fresh verified backup of your database before you try to change the table. And by *verified* I mean that you have successfully restored your backup into a test database.