# Change MySQL numerical field to char using a function

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL DB with a field for storing IP address. It stores it as a number (int). I'd like to change the structure to use string (char) instead.

Is it possible with single ALTER TABLE statement? As far as I can see in Postgres it is possible to specify a conversion function to ALTER TABLE, but I don't see an equivalent for MySQL.

A workaround is of course to:

- alter table by adding a new char() field
- update that new field from the old one using inet_ntoa
- alter table by removing old field
- and finally renaming new field to the same name as the old one had

But maybe there is a simpler solution?

Comment: IP addresses are strings, right?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465601/how-will-changing-the-mysql-field-type-from-int-to-varchar-affect-data-previousl

Comment: @Strawberry - no. They are stored as result of `inet_aton`. For example "10.201.111.4" is stored as 180973316.

Comment: @StefanR - this is a similar but not the same. I want to convert something like 180973316 back to string representing ip. I'm not interested converting that to string "180973316".

Comment: So what's wrong with inet_ntoa?

Comment: I'd like to have the value in the DB as string for easy inserting and getting (without using select inet_ntoa(ip) from ...) and, the most important, to be able to store host address as a *domain name* and not just IP. That is why a solution with using inet_ntoa is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply alter the column to varchar. mysql will automatically convert the values. I can confirm this with mysql 5.6.
but before you do this, you should definetely create a backup and maybe try this with a small test table.

Comment: Well, it will not work for me. I have IPs converted to 1 number and stored. For example "10.201.111.4" is stored as 180973316. If you convert it to varchar I will get "180973316". But I want "10.201.111.4".

Comment: @MirekOpoka So, it's a two-stage process. Or create a separate column or table for the converted ips.